# can I pip install from github with the editable option and push back up to github

Tags: git, pip

I have a git repository that I'm installing using pip into a conda virtual environment.  I'm using the `-e` option to make the directory in which I'm installing editable.  I anticipated that I could edit the code in place and when ready, push back up to the repository.

***Question 1***
Is this a common development work flow?

***Question 2***
I'm missing a few steps.  I can't push back up without some git related files.  What do I need to do to get this running?

***Question 3***
What should I be doing instead?